# What's the relationship between good will and duty?

Tags: metaphysics, kant

I'm writing an essay about the relationship between good will and duty, using an excerpt from Immanuel Kant's "Groundwork of the Metaphysics of Morals". I find the subject very interesting, but I'm not a philosophy student and I haven't worked much with texts like this, so I find the text a bit hard to understand. Does anyone have any suggestions on good articles or other texts that I should read to make the process of understanding his philosophy a bit easier? Or does anyone have some key words or notes that could help me in the direction of starting writing my essay?

Comment: I find the [SEP](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/kant-moral/) is a good resource; sections 2 & 3 cover good will and moral worth.